# about if statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, if-statement

```
SET @total_people = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_members);
SET @point_available = (SELECT free_bonus from tbl_bonus);

SET @must_use = @total_people * 15;

IF @point_available > @must_use THEN

SET @bonuses = @money_available - @must_use ;
UPDATE tbl_member SET points = points + 15 WHERE 1;
ELSE

SET @bonuses = @points_available / 15;
UPDATE tbl_member SET points = points + 15 LIMIT @bonuses;

END IF;

SELECT @bonuses
```

:( its not working :( ..... the whole if statement :'(

sorry about that XD .... newbie here ... and im trying to make it in english XD ... and its really hard to explain hahah btw ... im trying to make a stored procedure im having a problem with if statement ... i want to set a variable that handles total members .. and the total points i got ... free_points = total member * 15; if total points is greater than free points then do update tbl_member points = points + 15 all of them else some of them will get the free points ... limit total points / 15; sorry for bad english XD

error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF point_available > must_use THEN

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does it error, or not produce the output you were expecting, or what?

Comment: "*its not working*" is not a valid MySQL error message.

Comment: what is the problem and error,explain it please

Comment: sorry about that XD .... newbie here ... and im trying to make it in english XD ... and its really hard to explain hahah

btw ... im trying to make a stored procedure 

im having a problem with if statement ... 

i want to set a variable that handles total members .. and the total points i got  ...
free_points = total member * 15;
if total points is greater than free points then do 

update tbl_member points = points + 15 all of them

else

some of them will get the free points ... limit total points / 15;

sorry for bad english XD

Comment: Does you SQL have random HTML <br> tags in it?

Comment: no no no ... that <br> use here im trying to use enter .. sorry

Comment: You are missing the SET from the UPDATE statements

Comment: i forgot to add sorry ... but still not working :( ...

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF point_available > must_use THEN

Comment: Your `.` key is broken. It always inserts three characters when you press it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this one:

SET @point_available = (SELECT COUNT(free_bonus) from tbl_bonus);

Answer (score 0):

-_-

thnx everyone ... i found the solution ...

```
PREPARE STMT FROM 
"UPDATE tbl_member SET points = points + 15 LIMIT ? ";

SET @1st = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_member);
SET @2nd = (SELECT free_bonus FROM tbl_bonus);
SET @3rd = @1st * 15; 
SET @4th = @2nd / 15;
SET @5th = (SELECT IF(@3rd > @2nd,@4th,@1st));

EXECUTE STMT USING @5TH;
```

Comment: actually i accidentally construct it using other code found here in stock overflow -_-